# How to update/overwrite surface normal data in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've an object with custom normals set. It's a source for simply instacing some objects by using geometry nodes.

As soon as I use the "Realize Instances" node to get an exportable mesh, all my custom surface normals will be reset to the regular smooth version / get lost.

Is there a way to keep my custom normals surface infos or transfer them to my Realized Instances version including all distributed instaces?

Thank you
Chris

Comment: As far as I know, custom normals aren't supported yet.

Comment: How about data transfer from instanced geometry by topo after the GN?  Should apply and export just fine.

Comment: the problem is that they are realized, so that many separate instances becomes one joined mesh. So it should be very difficult to use data transfer here...

Comment: I guess normals can be baked into texture..

Comment: The data transfer modifier works with a source mesh, where normals have to came from. I would like to keep just one mesh and don't make a copy of it. And as @Crantisz writes: You need a realize instances node to transfer all normal data to the instances.

Comment: I need a realtime solution and can't bake normals to a texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As currently discussed [here](https://developer.blender.org/T93551), it is not possible to access or modify this data with *Geometry Nodes*.

Therefore, the problem cannot be solved currently (or in the foreseeable future).